# phantom crash when entering https url

Tags: phantomjs

```
var page = require('webpage').create();  
page.open('https://secure2.lionair.co.id/lionairibe/OnlineBooking.aspx', function (status) {

    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var p = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
        });
        console.log(p);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

I am getting this error : :
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the crash reporting guide at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Crash-Reporting and file a bug report at https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/entry with the crash dump file attached: /tmp/2b2956e8-26ff-b99e-68ba0a68-26e94c38.dmp
Segmentation fault (core dumped)